# Creating a programmatic login for web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to login using the HttpContext.SignInAsync inside a controller in .net core 2.0
The following is the same controller I used in .net core 1.1 and it worked fine.

```
[Route("Login/{username}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username)
{
        var userClaims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "custom")
        };

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "local"));
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync("DefaultAuthenticationScheme", principal);
        return Ok("done");
}
```

Then running the above code I see no output in the website. On debugging I don't see it crossing await line of code. I am assuming the function is getting completed before the SignInAsync function can run. But I didn't face that issue in core 1.1.

My changes to the startup.cs file are as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication("DefaultAuthenticationScheme")
        .AddCookie();
```

And in the Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I am also trying to create a filter that can do the same kind of login. However since I would be overriding the filter functions, I cannot make it an async function and hence can't call await on this async function.

Comment: just realized the reason I wasn't seeing any output for the async. To check for errors we can get the value of the task `var task = HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal)` and then check for errors with `task.Status` and then checking for the list of exceptions under `task.Exception`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **misunderstood** the concept as the `AddAuthentication` function takes in a string which would be a custom name for the configuration I set up. This name can later be used to reference the configuration in the `SignInAsync` function. 
Thanks to the pointers from @Mihali's answer, with some trial and errors I figured out how they actually work.

First of all the `SignInAsync` function takes in a string that refers to a scheme. For instance if I want the default scheme that stores cookies I could use "Cookies" like this:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", principal);
```

Alternatively, instead of "Cookies" we can always use the constant that stores the string `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as provided by @Mihali.

The string parameter in the `AddAuthentication` function takes in is meant to be set as the default scheme. This default scheme can be used directly in functions such as `SignInAsync` (above) and `SignOutAsync`. So I can have my start up config set up with a default scheme like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
        .AddCookie();
```

In this case I do not have to explicitly mention "Cookies" each time I use the sign in and sign out functions. I can simply use:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

This would use the default scheme set up in the startup.cs.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the `Authorize` attribute to the controller/methods you want have the redirect to Login if not authenticated/authorized.

**UPDATE**

I got it to work if you add this in your `ConfigureServices` method, replacing what you have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"));
```

Comment: Yeah I know about that. I have done that in another function to test as well. I seem to have issues in that as well. Either ways I was trying to fix this issue first. I have tested this function in debugger and it doesn't login.

Comment: regarding the redirect code. I wouldn't be using it since I am creating a web api. I just need the `Authorize` to return 400 or 403 not redirect. 
The first part of the code kindda helps with the solution. I am investigating the exact concepts and i'll update it